# java.lang.IllegalStateException android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren crash

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, crash, notifydatasetchanged

I edit this ticket.

I still see those crashes in prod. Rarely but I would like to understand what the issue is.

I have no data in the traces that could indicate where it crashed in my code.

What should I look for in my code based on the stack traces?

I googled on the terms java.lang.IllegalStateException android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren and I see that most of the comments are related to notifyDataSetChanged where the doc says:

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

I'm using about 10 listviews. I add items on the fly and they never change. If they do I clear the list and rebuild it from scratch.

Here is the stack traces:

Samsung Galaxy S6 (), 3072MB RAM, Android 7.0
Report 1 of 6

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1747)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout (AbsListView.java:3008)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1079)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1079)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1197)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout (ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:433)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1741)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:887)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2655)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2371)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7098)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:638)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: put some code with questions

Comment: like all my app? have you read the traces?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? I'm facing the exact same problem but it is hard to find out which part of the code is causing the issue without any class details in the stacktrace - it's nearly exact the same as your one

Comment: I got rid of this anr. I was adding the items in the doinbackround and in the publish (onProgress...) I was doing the notifydatasetchanged, you need to do both in the UI (ie publish or onpostexecute)

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the function

```
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after any add or remove from the ListView.